# Match multiple elements of array Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, match, element

I am using [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) to search over dirs. I then want to use `@ARGV` to match terms the user inputs. I only want the first to second last elements to be used for matching (last is an output name). I though my code would work but it isn't, any ideas?

```
if ($File::Find::name =~ m/$_/ for @ARGV[0..-2]){
    #manipulate filenames
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please define: `"match terms"`. Did you actually mean `"compare file names"`?

Comment: I mean use a match on the elements held in @ARGV, ie if I run `perl script.pl match1 match2 output` I want to match the terms "match1" and "match2" to the path.

Comment: That explanation would not have helped even if it had come 6 hours ago. When in doubt, use an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXPR for LIST` is a statement, not an expression. `if (COND) {BLOCK}` expects `COND` to be an expression.

You can embed a block into an expression via `do {BLOCK}`, but this won't quite do what you want.

If you want to express “manipulate filename if any item of the list matches”, do

```
if (grep { $File::Find::name =~ /$_/ } LIST) { ... }
```

If you want to express “manipulate filename if all items of the list match”, do

```
if (not grep { not $File::Find::name =~ /$_/ } LIST) { ... }
```

You cannot slice an array like `@array[0..-2]` as the range operator isn't special in array subscripts; the range from 0 to -2 is empty. Rather: `@array[0 .. @array-2]`.

Comment: Thanks, the `not grep` is exactly what I needed. Very interesting to see the syntax for `@array[0..@array-2]`. I have defined a variable to use: `my $largv=@ARGV-2; @ARGV[0..$largv]` which works similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use `$File::Find::name` here? That's the relative path and not just the file name. I assume you are trying to match file names here. Here's what you do:

```
my $output = pop @ARGV;             # now you can use @ARGV freely
my $regex  = join "|",              # join by alternations
                 map quotemeta,     # disable meta characters
                 @ARGV;             # list of file names
find(sub { 
        /$regex/i or return;        # quick check
        # manipulate files...
     }, $dir);
```

There are tweaks you can do, such as disable meta characters or not, using case insensitivity or not `/.../i`.

Documentation: [pop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html), [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html), [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: Your assumption that I want to match filename is incorrect, I have multiple files in different dirs named the same thing (bad idea, I know!) and am trying to just find some of these files based on the dir as well as file name. Thank you for the response though, it is interesting in itself.

Comment: @bruce01 Yes, "match terms" was not exactly crystal clear. But I think you fail to see the point in my answer: Instead of using a loop, you compile a regex to compare the path to. So, switch `/$regex/` to `$File::Find::name =~ /$regex/`.

Comment: I think it was pretty clear: the convention `$str =~ m/sthng/` is a match statement, and what I want to match are terms. What is the correct nomenclature here? I do see what you are doing, I just used the other method above as I see it being more clear for myself when returning to the script. Thanks again for your time and help on this, I do appreciate it.